# Backbone.js: Build JSON array from collection

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection `Platforms`.  The structure of `Platforms` looks like this:

```
Platforms
  PlatformList
    models
      0: Platform
        attributes
          id: 1
          name: "some name"
      1: Platform
        attributes
          id: 2
          name: "some other name"
```

I need to extract the attributes from the models within the collection, and build a JSON array in the following format:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"some name"},{"id":2,"name":"some other name"}]
```

Calling `Platforms.models.toJSON()` or `JSON.stringify(Platforms.models)` results in a literal string `"[[object Object], [object Object]]"`

How can I build the JSON array that I need from this collection?

Comment: Taking a quick look at the [annotated source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html), it looks like you might try Platforms.toJSON()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you should not do platforms.models.toJSON()
but instead call toJSON on the collection itself!

```
Platforms.toJSON()
```

check the following jsfiddle on this solution
http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/TP9NE/2/